# BIND9 server not responding to external queries

Tags: 12.04, dns, bind

I have set up a BIND server on my dedicated box which I want to host a nameserver for my domain on.

When I use `dig @202.169.196.59 nzserver.co.nz` locally on the server I get the following response...

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @202.169.196.59 nzserver.co.nz
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43773
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nzserver.co.nz.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nzserver.co.nz.         3600    IN      A       202.169.196.59

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nzserver.co.nz.         3600    IN      NS      ns2.nzserver.co.nz.
nzserver.co.nz.         3600    IN      NS      ns1.nzserver.co.nz.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.nzserver.co.nz.     3600    IN      A       202.169.196.59
ns2.nzserver.co.nz.     3600    IN      A       202.169.196.59

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 202.169.196.59#53(202.169.196.59)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 27 15:40:45 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

Which is good, and is the output I want. But when simply using `dig nzserver.co.nz` I get...

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> nzserver.co.nz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 16970
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nzserver.co.nz.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 308 msec
;; SERVER: 202.169.192.61#53(202.169.192.61)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 27 17:09:12 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

And if I use `dig @202.169.196.59 nzserver.co.nz` on another linux machine I get...

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @202.169.196.59 nzserver.co.nz
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Port 53 is definitely open.

---

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        forwarders {
                202.169.192.61;
                202.169.206.10;
        };

        listen-on {
                202.169.196.59;
        };
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "nzserver.co.nz" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/nzserver.co.nz.zone";
};
```

**/etc/bind/nzserver.co.nz.zone**

```
; BIND db file for nzserver.co.nz

$ORIGIN nzserver.co.nz.

@       IN      SOA     ns1.nzserver.co.nz. mr.steven.french.gmail.com. (
2012102606
28800
7200
864000
3600 )

        NS      ns1.nzserver.co.nz.
        NS      ns2.nzserver.co.nz.
        MX      10 mail.nzserver.co.nz.

@       IN      A       202.169.196.59
*       IN      A       202.169.196.59
ns1     IN      A       202.169.196.59
ns2     IN      A       202.169.196.59
www     IN      A       202.169.196.59
mail    IN      A       202.169.196.59
```

**netstat -tupanl | grep ":53 "**

```
tcp        0      0 202.169.196.59:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8250/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8250/named
udp        0      0 202.169.196.59:53       0.0.0.0:*                           8250/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           8250/named
```

Comment: Perhaps you have another nameserver or something else already listening on UDP port 53? It works if I query your nameserver via TCP but not via UDP. Check the logs for errors when the nameserver starts up. It is probably not succeeding to bind to its configured address. Also, you probably shouldn't have `forwarders` in your config but rather `recursion no;` instead if this is intended to be an authoritative nameserver.

Comment: I added netstat of port 53 to the bottom of the question. Everything looks fine there? I'll take a look at the logs and see if anything is wrong there, or else.. could port 53 be blocked for UDP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a good amount of testing I found that the firewall was still blocking the UDP port. I got the data center to do some more checks and they did a refresh of the firewall rules, which unblocked the port.

Things to note...

`nmap -sU [IP] -p 53` was returning open/filtered. After making sure it wasn't anything wrong with my server I concluded there was a problem with the data center firewall.

Comment: That sounds like the problem I am having! My ISP had problems today with some DoS and once resolved I could not access my name server with UDP. I could use TCP and that worked just fine though proving that our name server is indeed working...

Comment: With dig you can check wether or not a specific nameserver (here it is googles public dns) allows `tcp` traffic on port `53`: `dig your.domain.org @8.8.8.8 +tcp` . In this fashion you can test your private nameserver or your ISPs nameservers if something is blocked through a firewall or ACL.